# Return value in perl XML::DOM

Tags: perl, list

I am working on a Perl code using XML::DOM.

I found in Perl help(XML::DOM::Node) stating as below.

```
@list = $node->getChildNodes;        # returns a perl list
$nodelist = $node->getChildNodes;    # returns a NodeList (object reference)
for my $kid ($node->getChildNodes)   # iterate over the children of $node
```

If I pass it in my function as below.

```
&myfunction($node->getChildNodes)
```

I am not getting the reference to the list.

Is there any way to get the reference with out declaring temporary scalar variable, like below.

```
my $tmp=$node->getChildNodes;
&myfunction($tmp)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunction([ $node->getChildNodes ])

myfunction(scalar $node->getChildNodes)
```

The second avoids creating a new array and a new reference, but the first might be clearer.

---

PS — Why are you telling Perl to ignore the prototype on `myfunction`? Don't use `&`.